# Folder display mode olFolderDisplayNoNavigation causing artifacts in Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, add-in

A Outlook Add-in explorer window with the folder display mode setting `olFolderDisplayNoNavigation` is causing errors within the GUI of Outlook 2013. In Outlook 2010 the setting worked fine, but now it shows artifacts / UI glitches on the left menu pane, which should not be displayed at all. Is there any way to fix this behavior?

```
public void open_myExplorer(IRibbonControl control)
{            
   Recipient myRecipient = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CreateRecipient("user@email.com");

   MAPIFolder mFolder  = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderNotes);

   Explorer myExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers.Add(mFolder, OlFolderDisplayMode.olFolderDisplayNoNavigation);

   myExplorer.Display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using

```
myExplorer.NavigationPane.IsCollapsed = true;
myExplorer.ShowPane(OlPane.olNavigationPane, false);
```

instead of setting the display mode to olFolderDisplayNoNavigation.